# MAME saving but not restoring games

Tags: compiling

**Background**

I discovered Ms. PacMan some time ago, but you don't see many of that game in arcades. Then I did find out about [`mame` (version 0.145)](http://mamedev.org/), available on my Linux (Ubuntu) machine and about running Ms. PacMan and that works.

**Problem**

When I save a game (so I don't have to start from the beginning every time (so to improve more difficult levels) and then restore the game, the game in MAME resets and I have to start from the beginning.

I have read [here](http://mamedev.org/devwiki/index.php?title=FAQ%3aFeatures) about games being updated to support save state and also somewhere that saving was removed from MAME .100. I also tried to compile an older MAME version 0.99 (which should support saving), but it has no Linux support. And [AdvanceMAME (1.2)](http://advancemame.sourceforge.net/) does not compile because of configuration file problems that don't seem easy to solve.

**Question**

Should I try harder to get an old MAME compiled, or is this saving of Ms. PacMan not going to work on Linux anyway?

Comment: Note the `sdlmame` 0.152 package is [available](http://sdlmame.wallyweek.org/) for Ubuntu as of Jan 25th 2014...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling and setting up `mame` or `advancemame`, with svgalib or newer replacements is not easy. You should stick with the working version of `mame` that you have.

If you get the message that the game is properly restored, the first thing to try is restoring from the same position a second time, do this while the system is 'resetting' the game. That often helps (but not always).

What should almost certainly solve the issue is saving a game while you are playing (and not at the beginning of a new level), the latter never worked for me without having problems reloading, the former always worked.

When saving in the middle of a level, make sure Blinky & co are not too close, so you have time to get your hands back in position on the keyboard/joystick after restoring.